# SQL select string after second occurrence of a character

Tags: mysql, sql

I am selecting 4 columns of data:

```
HES_CODE_COMBINATIONS.ANALYSIS_CODE_1,
HES_CODE_COMBINATIONS.ANALYSIS_CODE_7,
HES_CODE_COMBINATIONS.ANALYSIS_CODE_8, 
HES_CODE_COMBINATIONS.DESCRIPTION
```

I want to trim the description column

```
(**HES_CODE_COMBINATIONS.DESCRIPTION**)
```

to keep only the text string after the second occurrence of `"."` (full stop)

E.g. From:

**Research (R Codes).Other Income Projects.Defects in cellular DNA repair mechanisms ~ 01/09/14 - 31/08/16**

To retrieve only:

**Defects in cellular DNA repair mechanisms ~ 01/09/14 - 31/08/16**

Thanks

Comment: You have to parse retrived string, which language you are using?. If php use explode()

Comment: You can use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX`  to get what you want

Comment: Are you sure there are only 2 `"."` in a string

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but it's useful and this should work

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DESCRIPTION, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(DESCRIPTION, '.', 2)) + 2) FROM HES_CODE_COMBINATIONS;
```

The third argument in `SUBSTRING_INDEX` (`2`) is the number of the occurrence you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT substring_index(your_column, '.', -1) FROM test_table
```

this will match the string from the right to the first occurance of '.' (from the right)

this will match string after second occurance of '.'

```
SELECT substring(your_column from length(substring_index(your_column, '.', 2))+2) FROM test_table
```

Comment: If there are more than 2 `"."` then??

Comment: Yes there are some entries with more than one "." However I want to keep everything after the second "."

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
DECLARE @stringvalue VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Research (R Codes).Other Income Projects.Defects in cellular DNA repair mechanisms ~ 01/09/14 - 31/08/16' 
SELECT SUBSTRING( @stringvalue, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX( @stringvalue,'.',2))+2,LENGTH( @stringvalue));
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: do you see the mysql tag ?

Comment: Yes I Do. And i have executed it on MYSQL. After that only i have posted my answer here. Is my answer not correct.??

Comment: it did not execute in mysql for me

Comment: Try it by replacing the string with variable.

Comment: This looks promising, thank you for taking the time to do this.  Keep getting interrupted, will give this a shot tomorrow morning!